# Dynamically show/hide Header or Footer of Xamarin.Forms.ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to dynamically show/hide the header of a ListView based on a condition at runtime.

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewChallenges" Header="{Binding .}">

    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="No Elements found." IsVisible="{Binding FooterIsVisible}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.FooterTemplate>

    <!-- ... -->

</ListView>
```

In the BindingContext I have declared the FooterIsVisible property. When it is false, the footer should be invisible. However this is not working, the Footer is always consuming a certain space for the Label at the bottom of the ListView.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to hide the footer and not have it consume any space. I believe you'll need to set the `HeightRequest` for the label in the `FooterTemplate`.  You can do that by doing something like:

```
<Label Text="No Elements found." IsVisible="{Binding FooterIsVisible}">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <Trigger TargetType="Label" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="0" />
        </Trigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

Comment: I tried HeightRequest before, but it doesn't work. The Footer is ignoring it and still consuming that space, even if triggering ForceLayout on the parenting ContentView.

Comment: Are you working with iOS, Android, or something else?  I just ran a quick test on this code on Android toggling the `FooterIsVisible` on and off and it appeared to work as far as I understand the problem.  I don't have access to my Mac at the moment, so I can't check it out on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for checking that. I did try it again on both iOS and Android and you're right for Android. There it works, so the problem only exists on iOS. Once the footer has been visible, it will remain to consume that same space even when invisible. That might be a bug. I'm under the impression that Xamarin is not really reacting on "smaller" issues - so I guess I have to live with it.

Comment: I filed this as a bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51961

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the footer because the listview is empty just set

```
listview.footer = null
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use FooterTemplate and Footer properties. It works as ItemTemplate and ItemSource:

```
<ListView Footer="{Binding IsFooterVisible}">
    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Footer content. Always visible -->
        </DataTemplate>
    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And bind to Footer property something nullable (object for example). Or you can use converter to convert: true -> new object() and false -> null

Also it is possible to create a subclass of ListView. My example (IsLoading property is what you searching for):

Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Panor.Views.LoadableListView"
    x:Name="element"
    >
    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="true"
                    Margin="0, 5"
                    Color="{StaticResource mainColor}"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    >
                    <ActivityIndicator.Scale>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="2" Android="1" />
                    </ActivityIndicator.Scale>
                </ActivityIndicator>
            </ContentView>            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.FooterTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class LoadableListView : ListView
{
    public LoadableListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ItemAppearing += OnItemAppearing;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsLoadingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(IsLoading),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(LoadableListView),
        false,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => 
        {
            var element = (LoadableListView)bindable;

            element.Footer = (bool)newValue ? new object() : null;
        }
    );
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        set => SetValue(IsLoadingProperty, value);
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsLoadingProperty);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ScrolledDownCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(ScrolledDownCommand),
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(LoadableListView)
    );
    public ICommand ScrolledDownCommand
    {
        set => SetValue(ScrolledDownCommandProperty, value);
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(ScrolledDownCommandProperty);
    }

    void OnItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemsSource == null) return;
        if (ScrolledDownCommand == null) return;

        object last = null;

        if (ItemsSource is IList)
        {
            var length = (ItemsSource as IList).Count;
            last = (ItemsSource as IList)[length - 1];
        }
        else 
        {
            foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
                last = item;
        }

        if (e.Item == last && ScrolledDownCommand.CanExecute(null))
            ScrolledDownCommand.Execute(null);

    }
```

Consuming:

```
 <views:LoadableListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource}"
                RowHeight="120"
                SeparatorColor="#c7c8c9" 
                IsLoading="{Binding IsMoreLoading}"
                ScrolledDownCommand="{Binding ScrolledDownCommand}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                >
                <views:LoadableListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <cells:MagazinesListCell Name="{Binding Name}" 
                            Publisher="{Binding Publisher}"
                            Price="{Binding Price}"
                            Image="{Binding Converter={StaticResource UriToImageSourceConvertor}, Path=Image}"
                            Commands="{Binding Commands}"
                            />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </views:LoadableListView.ItemTemplate>
            </views:LoadableListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your footer template in a `ViewCell`, then set the `ViewCell`'s `Height` to 0 when you don't want it to show. If you do this, make sure to set the `ListView.HasUnevenRows` property to `True`:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewChallenges" Header="{Binding .}" HasUnevenRows="True">

    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height={Binding FooterHeight}>
                <Label Text="No Elements found." IsVisible="{Binding FooterIsVisible}" />  
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.FooterTemplate>

<!-- ... -->

</ListView>
```

Comment: If using a ViewCell I get System.ArgumentException: Value was an invalid value for FooterTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```html
<ListView.FooterTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>

    <!--VIEW-->
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="true" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoadingOnDemand}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="15">
      <ActivityIndicator.Triggers>
        <Trigger TargetType="ActivityIndicator" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="0" />
        </Trigger>
      </ActivityIndicator.Triggers>
    </ActivityIndicator>

  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.FooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me without temlpate(template will not work if you need refer elements from the header in the parent .cs code). So have to containers with 0 and not 0 height and switch their visibility.

```
  <ListView.Header>
<StackLayout Style="{StaticResource DefaultStackLayout}">
    <StackLayout x:Name="ZeroHeaderContainer"
                 HeightRequest="0"
                 IsVisible="{Binding SomeBooleanField}"/>


    <StackLayout  x:Name="NormalHeaderContainer"
             Style="{StaticResource DefaultStackLayout}"
             HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
             IsVisible="{Binding SomeBooleanField,Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}">
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all variants with: 
1) `Header` property binding `new object()` or `null` 
2) Two stacklayouts with not converter (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53197844/7429947) 
3) `DataTrigger` and `Trigger` on change `IsVisible` set `HeightRequest`

This is doesn't help me, and then I replaced `MinimumHeightRequest` on 'HeightRequest' and second variant help me for iOS and Android!

Xamarin.Forms version: 4.6.0.726

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone else problem ASAP