# Dynamically show/hide search Xamarin.Forms.ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tried to show my SearchBar in my list view when swipe down,

so I have a hidden stacklayout when the screen is starting:

```
            <ListView 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Example}"
                    SeparatorVisibility="None"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.Header>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleHeader}">
                        <SearchBar x:Name="Search"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ListView.Header>
```

IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleHeader"} is a boolean property initialized to false.

I read this, [Dynamically show/hide Header or Footer of Xamarin.Forms.ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895092/dynamically-show-hide-header-or-footer-of-xamarin-forms-listview) but I can not change the value to true when I do swipe down in my list view and false when swipe up.

Is there any way to detect when I scroll? Or should I do some custom renders?

Comment: See if you can use a GestureRecognizer on your listview, for when you scroll down, but it might need some more complicated logic to work exactly as you are expecting. Is there an existing control on Nuget/Xamarin Component Store for a ListView with swipe-down-for-search?

Comment: I've been looking for days but I have not found anything about swipe-down-for-search. I try use GestureRecognizer, but I have not been able to specify when it's the first item in the list even I've even tried doing it when I refresh the list but ... nothing. I try use a header in a list view, and try show and hidden ... But i can change the value IsVisible